# Read a file line by line but only some characters within each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file and I would like to get the string from the 300th character to the 500th character (or column in the text file) within each line and put the string into a list.

I started my code with this but I don't know how to modify the file reading with specifying the ch.

```
with open("filename") as f:
for line in f:  
   for ch in line:
```

Comment: just use array slices: `for ch in line[300:500]: `

Comment: You can do that with something like `seq = [line[299:500] for line in f]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:  
       chs = line[299:500]
```

This should slice it and return the characters from 300-500. From there, you could just do `list.append` to put it into a list, or whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subscript slicing notation on python strings:

```
lines = []
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line[300:500])
```

Or

```
with open("filename") as f:
    lines = [l[300:500] for l in f]
```